# Private scoping with square brackets (private[...]) in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax, scope

I've come across the following syntax while looking through the Gatling source code:

```
private[http] def build = {
  // ...
}
```

What is the syntax inside square brackets?

When I click through it in my IDE it is an alias to a fully qualified package (`com.excilys.ebi.gatling.http`) but I can't find where that alias was defined.

Comment: might help if looking for an example https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-scala-method-scope-object-private-package

Answer (score 40):

See [the scala reference](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#private), specifically, chapter 5.2. Some excerpt:

> The private modiﬁer can be used with any deﬁnition or declaration in a template. Such members can be accessed only from within the directly enclosing template and its companion module or companion class (§5.4). They are
> not inherited by subclasses and they may not override deﬁnitions in parent
> classes.

> **The modiﬁer can be qualiﬁed with an identiﬁer C (e.g. private[C])** that must
> denote a class or package enclosing the deﬁnition. Members labeled with
> such a modiﬁer are accessible respectively only from code inside the package C or only from code inside the class C and its companion module (§5.4).
> Such members are also inherited only from templates inside C.

Comment: Making it short: private[http] make it private for com.excilys.ebi.gatling.http while private[gatling] would make it private for com.excilys.ebi.gatling. We make those private so they don't show up in IDE auto-completion.

Answer (score 12):

In short: this is used for **scope protection**:

- private[C] means that access is private "up to" C, where C is the
  corresponding package, class or singleton object.

Same to protected[C]

- protected[C]: access is protected "up to" C, where C is the
  corresponding package, class or singleton object.