# Scala AbstractSeq[A] location

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

```
 sealed abstract class List[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A] with LinearSeq[A] with Product with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, List] with LinearSeqOptimized[A, List[A]]
```

Where is AbstractSeq[A] location?

Answer (score 4):

It's exactly where it says it is ([`scala.collection.AbstractSeq`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/56b7c0f8fa6c1037905867aec88520476dbd3baa/src/library/scala/collection/Seq.scala)). However, it's a [package-private class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706634/private-method-scoping-in-scala), and that's probably why it doesn't appear in the API. Here's its definition from 2.10.2:

```
/** Explicit instantiation of the `Seq` trait to reduce class file size in subclasses. */
private[scala] abstract class AbstractSeq[+A] extends AbstractIterable[A] with Seq[A]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Swift Tomato's answer, a bit of background - not having the `AbstractSeq` would mean that the Scala compiler must instantiate bridge methods for methods in `Seq` for every collection class that extends trait `Seq`. This compiler trick is needed to support multiple inheritance on the JVM.

Having all the concrete collection extend `AbstractSeq` allows concrete collections to inherit those bridge methods like any other JVM method, so the compiler does not need to instantiate bridge methods in every concrete collection class -- the class-file sizes of those concrete collections are reduced.

This class is private and visible only in the `scala` package to avoid further convoluting people's understanding of the collections package.